# Do I need a loop if I am only returning one row using SQLite? (Android Dev)

Tags: java, android

I have been using the following metod using a for loop but it occurred to me that I am only returning one row- so is it necessary to have a loop?

i.e my code resembles this:

```
public String topSwimmerSponsor() {
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_SWIMMERLAPS + " * "
            + KEY_SPONSOR + " AS result, " + KEY_NAME + " FROM "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " ORDER BY result DESC limit 1", null);

    String result = "";

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        result = result + c.getString(1) + "\n";
    }
    return result;
}
```

However I am attempting to change it to the following:

```
public String topSwimmerSponsor() {
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_SWIMMERLAPS + " * "
            + KEY_SPONSOR + " AS result, " + KEY_NAME + " FROM "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " ORDER BY result DESC limit 1", null);

    String result = "";

    result = result + c.getString(1) + "\n";

    return result;
}
```

However my app crashes. What is the correct way to implement this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're only expecting one result you can use this:

```
if(c.moveToFirst())
  return c.getString(1) + "\n";
```

Comment: I get an error, it says that the method must return a string type.

Comment: if(c.moveToFirst())
      return c.getString(1) + "\n";
    else
      return "";

Comment: put `return null;` at the end of the method.

Answer (score 2):

You should still move to the first position and check that you have a row:

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    result = c.getString(1) + "\n";
}
```

Also, using string concatenation in a loop is a very bad idea, especially in an android environment, because it creates lots of temporary StringBuilder and String objects that have to be allocated and garbage collected. You should use a StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (...) {
    builder.append(...);
    builder.append(...);
}
String result = builder.toString();
```

Comment: +1 - for great information about allocation of StringBuilder and String Objects